# How to allocate two different functions to the same button?

Tags: c#, winforms, function, button

I am working on Winforms with C#.

I have a problem with the logic, there are two different methods that I need to call, so that if I click the button, the first action should get applied and if I click the same button again, the second action should get applied.

This is not the exact code but I have an idea something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(button1.click==true)
    {
        fileNumber = 1;
        ImgSave();
    }
    else
    {
        ImgSave.exit();
    }
}
```

Here I have two problems regarding whether the button is already clicked:

- If it's not clicked the `Imgsave()` should get activated.
- If button is clicked the `Imgsave()` should get closed.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a restriction on the number of buttons you can put on a form ? :-)

Comment: yes., I need to use only one button, for two different function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep state somewhere. You can do this:

```
private bool buttonClicked = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!buttonClicked)
    {
        buttonClicked = true;
        fileNumber = 1;
        ImgSave();
    }
    else
    {
        ImgSave.exit();
    }
}

This assumes you never going to click it a third time. If you are, you would need to handle that in some way.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have either a class level variable track the number of times a button is clicked:

```
private bool _unclicked = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!_unclicked)
    {
        _unclicked = true; //toggle so next time the ELSE will be performed
        fileNumber = 1;
        ImgSave();
    }
    else
    {
        _unclicked = false; //toggle it off again
        ImgSave.exit();
    }
}
```

, or I'd store it in the .Tag of the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!button1.Tag.ToString() == "unclicked")
    {
        button1.Tag = "clicked"; //toggle so next time the ELSE will be performed
        fileNumber = 1;
        ImgSave();
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Tag = "unclicked"; //toggle it off again
        ImgSave.exit();
    }
}
```

You could also remove one event handler and add another:

```
private void button1_FirstClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Clicked -= button1_FirstClick;             
    button1.Clicked += button1_SecondClick;             
    fileNumber = 1;
    ImgSave();
}

private void button1_SecondClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Clicked -= button1_SecondClick;             
    button1.Clicked += button1_FirstClick;             
    ImgSave.exit();
}
```

I've always been less of a fan of adding and removing event handlers to achieve things like this but it's quite a clean solution

Answer (score 1):

You should save your state in a variable. Your state will change after first click and you can change the state of Clicking button with calling `ConditionChanger()` method anytime.

For example you may need change the state of variable when you clicked a second button.

```
private void ConditionChanger(){
    myState = !myState;
}
```

Your variable :

```
private bool myState = false;
```

And your click event :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!myState)
    {
        myState = true;
        fileNumber = 1;
        ImgSave();
    }
    else
    {
        ImgSave.exit();
    }
}
```